# FatalErrorException in Model.php line 986: Class 'App\Role' not found

Tags: laravel

My `routes.php` file is

```
<?php
use App\models\User;
use App\models\Permission;
use App\models\Role;

Route::get('/roles', function()
{
 //code
}
```

and my `role.php` file is

```
 <?php
 namespace App\models;
 use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;

 class Role extends EntrustRole
 { 

 }
```

and I found the error like this

> FatalErrorException in Model.php line 986: Class 'App\Role' not found

Comment: What is `Model.php` ? If the error comes from that file you'd better to show it

Comment: role.php is model file..anyhow thanks for helping...i solved that error @Moppo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Entrust config file looks for models inside the `App` namespace, not the `App\models` namespace. You need to publish the config file and update it accordingly:

```
'role' => 'App\models\Role',
```